# Check SQL Database for Exisiting Email Address If-then ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to check the SQL database to see if the email inputted by the user registering already exists. If it does, then I want an error message popup saying it's already registered. If not, then they should have successfully registered. This is the only remaining check I need with my form. The problem section is notated with *** below. Please help!

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.Sql
Imports System.Data.SqlTypes
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls


Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim boolCar As Object

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    ' declare database input variables
    Dim userId As Integer = 0
    Dim firstName As String = txtFirstName.Text
    Dim lastName As String = txtLastName.Text
    Dim hometown1 As String = txtHometown1.Text
    Dim state1 As String = txtState1.Text
    Dim zip1 As String = txtZipCode1.Text
    Dim hometown2 As String = txtHometown2.Text
    Dim state2 As String = txtState2.Text
    Dim zip2 As String = txtZipCode2.Text
    Dim phoneNum As String = txtPhoneNumber.Text
    Dim emailAddress As String = txtEmailAddress.Text
    Dim password As String = txtPassword.Text
    Dim boolCar As Boolean = False
    Dim boolUmary As Boolean = False

    If radYesNo.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        boolCar = True
    Else
        boolCar = False
    End If

    If txtEmailAddress.Text.Contains("@umary.edu") Then
        boolUmary = True
    Else
        boolUmary = False
    End If

        If boolUmary = True And txtPassword.Text = txtRetypePassword.Text Then


        If (IsPostBack) Then
            ' this creates the connection. It assumes you have your SQL Express database file in the App_Data directory
            Dim sqlConn As New SqlConnection("Server=CISWEB\UMCISSQL2008;Database=StudentGov;UId=sa;Password=Password1;")

            Dim sqlCmd As New SqlCommand ' create the command object

            Dim _SqlDataReader As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader = Nothing

            sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn ' define the connection for the command object

            ' define the command using parameterized query 
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO RegisteredUsers(FirstName, LastName, Hometown1, State1, ZIP1, Hometown2, State2, ZIP2, PhoneNum, UMaryEmail, Password, Car) VALUES (@txtFirstName, @txtLastName, @txtHometown1, @txtState1, @txtZipCode1, @txtHometown2, @txtState2, @txtZipCode2, @txtPhoneNumber, @txtEmailAddress, @txtPassword, @RadYesNo)"

            ' define the SQL parameter
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtFirstName", txtFirstName.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtLastName", txtLastName.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtHometown1", txtHometown1.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtState1", txtState1.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtZipCode1", txtZipCode1.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtHometown2", txtHometown2.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtState2", txtState2.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtZipCode2", txtZipCode2.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPhoneNumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPassword", txtPassword.Text)
            sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RadYesNo", boolCar)


            sqlConn.Open() ' open connection
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ' execute the data insertion

            *****Dim message As String = String.Empty
            //' no idea whats going on here
            //' What needs to happen - IF the UMaryEmail value ISNULL THEN message = Registration successful + SendActivationEmail(userId)
            //' ELSE (IF UMaryEmail != ISNULL) message = Supplied email address already in use
            sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT VALUE = CASE WHEN LEN(ISNULL(UMaryEmail,'))=0 Then '" + txtEmailAddress.ToString + "' WHEN LEN(ISNULL(UMaryEmail,'))!=0 THEN UMaryEmail END FROM RegisteredUsers;"
                Select Case userId
                    Case -10
                        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT RegisteredUsers.UMaryEmail FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE(RegisteredUsers.UMaryEmail = '" + txtEmailAddress.ToString + "');"
                        message = "Supplied email address has already been used."
                        Exit Select
                    Case Else
                        message = "Registration successful. An activation email has been sent to the email provided."
                        SendActivationEmail(userId)
                        Response.Redirect("ActivateAccount.aspx")
                        Exit Select
                End Select*****


                ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "alert", (Convert.ToString("alert('") & message) + "');", True)

                sqlConn.Close() ' close connection

        ElseIf txtPassword.Text <> txtRetypePassword.Text Then
                MsgBox("The passwords do not match!")

        ElseIf boolUmary = False Then
                MsgBox("Please use your UMary email address!")
        End If
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub SendActivationEmail(userId As Integer)
    Dim sqlString As String = "Server=CISWEB\UMCISSQL2008;Database=StudentGov;UId=sa;Password=Password1;"
    Dim ActivationCode As String = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    Using con As New SqlConnection(sqlString)
        Using sqlCmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE RegisteredUsers SET UserId = '" + userId.ToString + "', ActivationCode = '" + ActivationCode.ToString + "' WHERE UMaryEmail='" + txtEmailAddress.Text + "';")
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId)
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ActivationCode", ActivationCode)
                sqlCmd.Connection = con
                con.Open()
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    Using mm As New MailMessage("mariders@umary.edu", txtEmailAddress.Text)
        mm.Subject = "Account Activation"
        Dim body As String = "Hello " + txtFirstName.Text.Trim() + ","
        body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account"
        body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("VB.aspx", Convert.ToString("VB_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=") & ActivationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>"
        body += "<br /><br />Thanks"
        mm.Body = body
        mm.IsBodyHtml = True
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
        smtp.Host = "smtp.live.com"
        smtp.EnableSsl = True
        Dim NetworkCred As New NetworkCredential("trialmaps2014@outlook.com", "12Password")
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred
        smtp.Port = 587
        Try
            smtp.Send(mm)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Email was not sent")
        End Try
    End Using
End Sub
End Class
```

I tried using a Select Case statement as you can see above, but for some reason it does not work. So I am flummoxed as how to convert the result of the SQL query into a VB variable that would be used in an IF-THEN statement.

Comment: As it is your SQL query won't even run. Look at your second ISNULL parameter.

Comment: Yes, I'm very well aware that it won't run. It's not supposed to run right now, I'm still trying to figure out how to do it. That's why I'm asking how do I even go about doing it? I'm inexperienced with SQL queries.

Comment: There are a couple of issue I see here. 

Firstly, if you are going to validate email, you should do so at the very top. 

Secondly, if your validation passes, then you should use the same connection to complete the registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
   If txtEmailAddress.Text.Trim.EndsWith("@umary.edu") Or txtPassword.Text.Trim = txtRetypePassword.Text.Trim Then
      Dim con As New SqlConnection
      Dim cmdEmail As New SqlCommand
      Dim cmdRegistration As New SqlCommand
      Dim EmailCount As Integer = 0

      Try
         con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SERVERNAME;Initial Catalog=StudentGov;User ID=sa;Password=Password1"
         con.Open()

         cmdEmail = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(UMaryEmail) As EmailCount FROM RegisteredUsers WHERE UMaryEmail='" & txtEmailAddress.Text.Trim & "'", con)
         EmailCount = cmdEmail.ExecuteScalar()

         If EmailCount <> 0 Then
            ' Declare database input variables '
            Dim userId As Integer = 0
            Dim firstName As String = txtFirstName.Text
            Dim lastName As String = txtLastName.Text
            Dim hometown1 As String = txtHometown1.Text
            Dim state1 As String = txtState1.Text
            Dim zip1 As String = txtZipCode1.Text
            Dim hometown2 As String = txtHometown2.Text
            Dim state2 As String = txtState2.Text
            Dim zip2 As String = txtZipCode2.Text
            Dim phoneNum As String = txtPhoneNumber.Text
            Dim emailAddress As String = txtEmailAddress.Text
            Dim password As String = txtPassword.Text
            Dim boolCar As Boolean = False
            Dim boolUmary As Boolean = False

            If radYesNo.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
               boolCar = True
            Else
               boolCar = False
            End If

            ' Define the command using parameterized query '
            cmdRegistration = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO RegisteredUsers(FirstName, LastName, Hometown1, State1, ZIP1, Hometown2, State2, ZIP2, PhoneNum, UMaryEmail, Password, Car) VALUES (@txtFirstName, @txtLastName, @txtHometown1, @txtState1, @txtZipCode1, @txtHometown2, @txtState2, @txtZipCode2, @txtPhoneNumber, @txtEmailAddress, @txtPassword, @RadYesNo)", con)

            ' Define the SQL parameter '
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtFirstName", txtFirstName.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtLastName", txtLastName.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtHometown1", txtHometown1.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtState1", txtState1.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtZipCode1", txtZipCode1.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtHometown2", txtHometown2.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtState2", txtState2.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtZipCode2", txtZipCode2.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPhoneNumber", txtPhoneNumber.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtEmailAddress", txtEmailAddress.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtPassword", txtPassword.Text)
            cmdRegistration.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RadYesNo", boolCar)

            cmdRegistration.ExecuteNonQuery()
         Else
            ' Duplicate Email Exist Error Message '            
         End If
      Catch ex AS Exception
         ' Error Executing One Of The SQL Statements '
      Finally
         con.close()
      End Try      
   Else
      ' Throw Error Message '
   End If
End Sub
```

If this answered your question, please mark this post as "Answered".

Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your input Moe S. But I'm still having issues with the SQL statement. First, I had to change the "If EmailCount <> 0 Then
" to "If EmailCount = 0 Then" because it was having the reverse effect. But that part does work now. However, when it goes through with a new email address entered, I get the catch error from "Catch ex AS Exception
         ' Error Executing One Of The SQL Statements '"

Comment: Ok, I'm glad you are making progress. You are correct, it should have been "=" instead of "<>". Anyway, you might want to try updating the SqlCommand line by concatenating the values instead of adding it as parameters. Let me know if it gives you an error message that is more useful.

Comment: Actually, I just removed the "Catch ex as Exception" because everything works now, even though it was catching. I'm not sure what it was doing so I just removed it and everything still works. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I was able to help. Also, don't vote up the answer. Thanks!